# Call JavaScript in  Pageload in VS2005

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
CheckBrow();
</script>


function  CheckBrow()
{
  if((navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ||(navigator.appName == "Netscape"))
  {
   HhdnBrowsertype.value=0;
  }
  else
  {
  alert("please open the application in IE or Fire fox browser")
  HhdnBrowsertype.value=1;
  }
}


<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HhdnBrowsertype" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript function.  Now I need to execute this function on page load.

Here I will check the browser type based on the hidden field value 0 or 1.

I will check this hidden field value on page load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// here  i need to call  my javscript  function
//  can any one  tell me the  syntax
          If(HhdnBrowsertype.Value==”1”)
    {
    // here  go my page load  function 
    }

        }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can call this JavaScript function on page load?  I am using VS 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<body onload="CheckBrow()">
```

or you can use.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "CheckBrow", "CheckBrow();", true);
```